How do you build Mizar locally?
Here is the recently open-sourced repo for the Mizar system.
It's pretty cool.
It's written in Pascal and appears to be compilable with using fpc with the -Mdelphi flag (found with trial and error).
At the very least, I can produce some object files locally by calling fpc -Mdelphi on various randomly chosen .pas files.
~/g/m/m/base (main)> fpc -Mdelphi info.pas
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2+dfsg-20 [2023/03/30] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2021 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling info.pas
Compiling errhan.pas
Compiling mconsole.pas
Compiling pcmizver.pas
Compiling mizenv.pas
996 lines compiled, 0.1 sec

However, the repo itself does not have a Makefile or similar and I am not sure how to build a single executable for the whole thing.
So, with that said, how do you build Mizar?

Also, there is a Rust version of Mizar now.  I don’t know if it is easier to compile (and it might be missing features), but it is at https://github.com/digama0/mizar-rs

@JasonRute That's only one component of the Mizar system (the verifier). It requires other components, but as I understand it can replace the verifier (and analyzer?) without any serious loss.

Roland Coghetto has written a script for compiling the Mizar source code to produce the binaries.
If you want to use it to check the entire MML, Roland has provided a Makefile which does that.

Should these be part of the Mizar repo, or at least linked to?

@JasonRute I tend to agree, these should be part of the Repo (or, some variation of it: I think the MML should be a separate repo with its own Makefile or build script). I'll file an issue and possible a PR to include a Makefile...

"If you want to use it to check the entire MML, Roland has provided a Makefile which does that." Sorry, I haven't yet updated the Makefile to the latest MML files.
